# Tengo problemas al abrir un fichero de texto con php

Tags: php

he estado tratando de añadir una cadena de texto a un fichero .txt desde php pero me salen estos errores

este es mi código:

```
<?php

$archivo = fopen("fichero_texto.txt", 'a+');

fwrite($archivo, "Soy el texto que añadiste al fichero");

while (!feof($archivo)) {
  $lectura = fgets($archivo);
  echo $lectura, "<br>";
}

fclose($archivo);
```

---

a la hora de correr todo me salen estos errores:
(según yo tengo asignado los permisos bien, no se lo que está fallando)

[image: Errores que salen al correr el archivo]

Comment: Valida que tengas los permisos correctos. Desde consola dirígete a la carpeta donde está el archivo y ejecuta `ls -l` e imprimirá los permisos del archivo.

Comment: el código es totalmente correcto, ya lo he probado; esto va mas por permisos del mismo, revisa lo que te comentan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error que estás obteniendo es porque el archivo que tratas de abrir no tiene los permisos suficientes para su lectura o edición.

#### ¿Cómo cambiar los permisos?

Existen dos comandos que serán de suma utilidad, primero está [`chmod`](https://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html) que nos permitirá modificar justamente dichos permisos y el otro es [`chown`](https://ss64.com/bash/chown.html) que sirve para modificar el propietario. Pero la mayoría de los casos se utiliza solo `chmod`.

#### ¿Cómo usarlo?

La forma más sencilla es darle permisos 7 (lectura, edición y ejecución) al archivo para todos los propietarios, quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
$ sudo chmod 777 /ruta/proyecto/archivo.txt
```

Con eso te evitarás un dolor de cabeza, pero definitivamente te recomiendo la lectura de como funciona para evitar vulnerar tu sistema ya que representa un gran riesgo en ambientes no controlados.

```
$ sudo chmod 755 /ruta/directorio
$ sudo chmod 644 /ruta/directorio/archivo.txt
```

[image: Tabla chmod]

*Tomada de: [Diario IFCD0110 Castro Urdiales](http://nuriaifcd0110castrourdiales.blogspot.com/2015/03/resumen-video-de-ubuntu.html)*

Comment: como sabes que esta en un entorno linux?

Comment: @shadow está en MacOS (lo identifiqué por las rutas), los comandos a los que hago referencia funcionan en entornos UNIX.

Comment: bien, excelente respuesta

Comment: modifiqué los permisos y funcionó todo correctamente, gracias